# Ubuntu 13.04 on Acer x64 PC, only boots after starting recovery

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I have this strange problem with my Acer E1 421.
First of all it's important to say that **I've upgraded this laptop's memory to 8gb RAM instead of 2**.

I decided to remove Windows 7 x64, and install Ubuntu, because I just hate Windows. The problem is, the install went all fine, but when I try to boot my laptop, this happens in order:

- Boot laptop
- Gets past BIOS Diagnostics
- I see the purple Ubuntu thing
- Screen goes black and stays that way until I press the Power off button
- Boot laptop again
- Gets past BIOS Diagnostics
- I get an Ubuntu screen where I can choose Boot Normal/Recovery/...
- I press Recovery
- I don't do anything, simply click "Continue to Normal boot"
- It works

Why do I always have to boot it up once, go through the whole recovery without actually doing anything, to get it booted?

I'm using the GRUB bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GRUB loads press `E`

Remove `quiet` and `splash` from the kernel line (starts with `linux`) so you can see the output of the bootup process.

Finally add `nomodeset` to the kernel line which will disable the loading of video drivers (for the splash screen) until X11 is loaded, which should be the fix.

EDIT: Once you've determined that this kernel parameter fixes the problem [edit the grub config](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation).